# How to use a flag in event listener callback in Android app

Tags: java, android, callback

#### Expected result

A button can act in a way like a toggle, such that,
(1) first time clicking on it, the button moves rightward
(2) second time clicking on it, the button moves leftward
(3) third time clicking on it, the button moves rightward
and so on....

#### Problem

The flag variable `flagToggleButton` cannot be used in button's OnClickListener event listener callback function.

#### Main.java

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        boolean flagToggleButton = false;
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (flagToggleButton == false) {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main.this, 
                                       R.anim.animation_move_right);
                    b.startAnimation(anim);
                    flagToggleButton = true;
                }
                else {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main.this, 
                                       R.anim.animation_move_left);
                    b.startAnimation(anim);
                    flagToggleButton = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, how is this related to Swing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a member variable of your class. In other words, define it outside `onCreate()`

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    boolean flagToggleButton = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Put globally

boolean flagToggleButton = false;

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!(flagToggleButton)) {
                    // do stuff..
                    flagToggleButton = true;
                }
                else {
                    // do stuff..
                    flagToggleButton = false;
                }
            }
        });
```